Stopped downloading with iCloud on Sonoma
The process of sync on iCloud from the Sonoma, that is really stuck me up. It seems to download to around 98% to 99% of the process, but it won't complete the sync. Even after restarting the computer, the issue persists. Is there any solution to this problem?


There might be a file or two which is holding up the process. Looking at the progress bar it is a very small amount of data (600,3 MB of 601,2 MB). If your iCloud Sync has been working well until now, perhaps a file with a very recent creation/edit date is at fault. Temporarily move a few recent files out of the source folder and re-sync.

Can you post the command output of brctl diagnose

Sorry I wasn't clear enough, it should generate a debug archive which you can upload somewhere for us to examine. (As described in https://eclecticlight.co/2018/04/12/diagnosing-icloud-problems-using-brctl-sync-budgets-and-throttles/) Not the output of command itself.
